# Why is my change sorting program returning absurd values? C++

Tags: c++

I've altered and changed many nuances within the program but all to the same avail.
Any input throws a redundant data loop.
adding a cout of entered_Amount below the while loop gives an inconceivably high number. I believe it to have something in relation to precision point numbers yet no clue whats going on.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    double entered_Amount;
    double q = 0.25; // q = quarter
    int qc = 0;      // qc = quarterCount
    double d = 0.10; // d = dime
    int dc = 0;      // dc = dimeCount
    double n = 0.05; // n = nickle
    int nc = 0;      // nc = nickleCount
    double p = 0.01; // p = penny
    int pc = 0;      // pc = pennyCount
    cout << "Enter a dollar amount: ";
    cin >> entered_Amount;

    while(entered_Amount > 0.00) {
        if (entered_Amount - q >= 0.00) {
            qc += 1;
            entered_Amount -= q;
        }

        else if (entered_Amount - d >= 0.00) {
            dc += 1;
            entered_Amount -= d;
        }

        else if (entered_Amount - n >= 0.00) {
            nc += 1;
            entered_Amount -= n;
        }

        else if (entered_Amount - p >= 0.00) {
            pc += 1;
            entered_Amount -= p;
        }
    }
    cout << entered_Amount << endl;
    cout << "Quarters: " << qc << endl;
    cout << "Dimes: " << dc << endl;
    cout << "Nickels: " << nc << endl;
    cout << "Pennies: " << pc << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, new to programming and hope I can give back to this community what I receive.

Comment: You'll find life much more pleasant and predictable if you use `int`s everywhere rather than a combination of `int` and `double`... which, for currency, you can do as long as you keep all your values in pennies rather than dollars.  That way you won't have to deal with round-off error and all the other "interesting" behaviors that go with floating-point math:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Floating-point numbers are for imprecise values, usually scientific measurements. The difference between 0.1 meters and 0.10000001 meters doesn't matter for any reasonable scientific purposes. The difference between 0.01 dollars and 0.0100000001 dollars is very significant, since 0.01 dollars is a precise number of pennies and the latter is nonsense. If you have exact quantities, you should be using `int`.

Comment: With the addition of an `else { break; }` after the `else if (entered_Amount - p >= 0.00) { }` the code worked for 4.40. Before that the loop was infinite in my testing because a very small positive amount was left over. With that said I expect you will have cases where the problem described in the duplicate will cause one count to be 1 less than you expect because perhaps the value is  something like `0.249999999999` to solve this you probably want to switch to integers and count in whole cents instead of using floating point math.